# Setting up Android Project / Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to learn Java for android application and so far I'm following a youtube tutorial. Since the guy posted it in 2011, some people in the comment section talked about skipping some steps because of the "new" ATP-bundle.

Here's the video I'm referring to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Da1jlmwuW_w

In this video the guy is installing SDK-manager and ATP-plugins, as recommended here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html. So what I'm wondering is if I can skip these steps and move on to creating an application project with the ATP-bundle?

Another question I have is if the rest of his videos (2011) are outdated and if I should find another source of tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed in 2 years. You should follow the documentation at developer.android.com. It's the official source.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html
I'm still confused by these two links. If I'm using the bundle, do I still have to download Android SDK, ADT plugin and install SDK tools using the manager? Or do the bundle include those?

Comment: No the ADT bundle includes Eclipse, the ADT plugin, and the SDK tools. However if you want to install older versions of Android you will need to go through the AVD manager in Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

The Recent version of android they are providing bundel (inclued ecplise and sdk every thing ). so if any updates are happened again we want to download the full off bundel, bz i face the problem usign that bundel. plz u can downlaod suprate Ecplise and Android Sdk and install. it very easy ..